# How to use DASH plugin in VScode?

Tags: visual-studio-code

[image]
I install Dash on my Visual Studio Code, but when I use ctrl + H ,tell me need to install dash-plugin by Microsoft store. However Microsoft store can find DASH. How should I do?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately Dash is currently Mac only